# Steam bot error - TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

http://prnt.sc/azsj2r

This error appears when im trying to make a bet on my betting site, the bot accepts the trade offer, but then the bot crashes

Comment: Show some code.. Whats the function where it fails? The error is a typical access to a property of an `undefined` variable.

Comment: will this help you? http://prnt.sc/azsn20

Comment: From the looks of it, you are trying to get element 0 from an undefined array at line 82 of Parser.js

Comment: alright, how do i solve it?

Comment: First thing: handle the `error`. Maybe it will give you valuable information about why is it failing, for example, is the SQL query valid?
Second: what is the return type of that query? Is it an `array`? I would guess that a `count` simply returns a `number`.
Third: do a `console.log(rows)`. What is the output? is it something you are expecting? is it `undefined`? 

Those are all scenarios that you should considered before posting a print screen and ask for help

Comment: to be honest i dont really have the experience to solve this by myself and i dont have alot of knowledge in "array"'s and whatever. is there anyone that can find a solution by this information i gave u?

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

1) Is the MySQL query correct?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT userid) AS playersCount From `game` + current_game
```

It seems wrong...
What I guess that you probably want is this:

```
'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS playersCount From `game` where id =' + current_game + ';'
```

2) Handle the error

```
function(err, rows) {
    if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
    }
    /*your code*/
}
```

This should give you an idea why the query fails.

3) What is the return type of that query? Is it what you are expecting it to be?

```
console.log(rows); //does this seems valid to you?
```